# GCC and Clang are behaving differently with respect to constant evaluation

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constant-expression, if-constexpr, consteval

I'm observing an inconsistency between GCC and Clang with respect to what is a constant evaluated context. I played with different situations:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

consteval auto ceval(auto x) { return x * x; }

constexpr auto constexprif(auto x) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(x)>) {
        return ceval(x);
    } else {
        return x + 2.;
    }
}
constexpr auto constexprif_consteval(auto x) {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<decltype(x)>) {
        if consteval {
            return ceval(x);
        } else {
            return x * x + 1;
        }
    } else {
        return x + 2.;
    }
}

constexpr auto constevalif(auto x) {
    if consteval {
        return ceval(x);
    } else {
        return static_cast<decltype(x)>(x + 2.);
    }
}

constexpr auto isconstantevaluated(auto x) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return ceval(x);
    } else {
        return static_cast<decltype(x)>(x + 2.);
    }
}

int main() {
#ifdef __clang__  // GCC KO
    auto a = constexprif(42);
    const auto b = constexprif(42);
    constexpr auto c = constexprif(42);
    std::cout << "constexprif " << a << '\t' << b << '\t' << c << '\n';
#endif
    auto d = constexprif_consteval(42);
    const auto e = constexprif_consteval(42);
    constexpr auto f = constexprif_consteval(42);
    std::cout << "constexprif_consteval " << d << '\t' << e << '\t' << f
              << '\n';
    auto g = constevalif(42);
    const auto h = constevalif(42);
    constexpr auto i = constevalif(42);
    std::cout << "constevalif " << g << '\t' << h << '\t' << i << '\n';
// auto j = isconstantevaluated(42);
#ifdef __clang__  // GCC KO
    const auto k = isconstantevaluated(42);
    constexpr auto l = isconstantevaluated(42);
    std::cout << "isconstantevaluated " << k << '\t' << l << '\n';
#endif
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/PKd3MMn77)

`ceval` is a basic `consteval` function, just to see in what context it can be called by a `constexpr` function.

`constexprif` is a function that (incorrectly) tried to return `ceval` if its argument is integral. Obviously, calling it with a runtime argument will not compile.

`constexprif_consteval` is a fixed version that will call `ceval`only in a constant evaluate context.

`constevalif` calls `ceval` in a constant evaluate context and should have the same output as `constexprif_consteval` for integral arguments.

Eventually, `isconstantevaluated` is the same as `constevalif` but with a `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` instead of an `if consteval`.

The output is as follows.

For GCC:

```
constexprif_consteval 1765    1764    1764
constevalif 44    1764    1764
```

For Clang:

```
constexprif 1764    1764    1764
constexprif_consteval 1764    1764    1764
constevalif 1764    1764    1764
isconstantevaluated 1764    1764
```

I took note of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822725/gcc-and-clang-disagree-on-whether-expression-is-constant-evaluated) about a Clang bug, but it's quite old now and I think that this question is going a bit deeper.

My expectations are the following. 
I think that GCC rightfully refuses `constexprif` in all situations because instantiating the function for an integral type may lead to use it in a runtime context. 
Clang seems overzealous to accept it in all cases, only on the basis that the argument is known at compile time.

With `constexprif_consteval` GCC seems to use the context (a non-`const` initialization) to chose the not `consteval` branch while Clang also goes for the full compile-time branch.

With `constevalif` we're observing the same behavior.

Eventually `isconstantevaluated` is always rejected by GCC, the `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())` being a runtime test.

Thus my impression is that GCC is correct with respect to my understanding of the standard so far. Is it so?
(yet, IMHO, the clang behavior seems easier to understand for me: arguments are known at compile-time? then the expression can be constant evaluated).

Comment: It might be beneficial to add/tweak tags so that `language-lawyer` is included.

Comment: Not read into it, but might be to do with [P2564R3](https://wg21.link/P2564R3), which [GCC claims to support in GCC14](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) and [Clang in clang17](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). Sure enough this doesn't compile on your godbolt link when you change from gcc13 -> gcc trunk

Answer (score 1):

Before [P2564](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2564r3.html) which was accepted for C++23, the situation was as follows:

`ceval(x)` is an invocation of an *immediate function* (i.e. a function marked `consteval`). Every invocation of an immediate function that is not in an *immediate function context*, i.e. either in the body of another `consteval` function or in the compound statement of a `if consteval`, is a so-called *immediate invocation* and must *itself* be a constant expression.

As you are saying, because `x` is not usable in constant expressions and its lifetime began outside of `ceval(x)`, `ceval(x)` itself can never be a constant expression.

As a result all of your attempts which use `if consteval` should succeed and all others should fail, as GCC is showing in your demonstration.

Whether the `if consteval` branch is taken depends on whether the context is *manifestly constant evaluated*. That's the case for the initializations of `f` and `i` because they are marked `constexpr` and for `e` and `h` because they are `const` integral type variables initialized by constant expressions (which makes them *usable in constant expressions* as well).

However, `d` and `g` are not *usable in constant expressions*, because they are neither of the two categories mentioned above. Furthermore they are not static storage duration and therefore their initialization is not *manifestly constant-evaluated*. In these cases the runtime evaluation should be used.

GCC in your demonstration seems to implement this correctly.

---

With P2564 the notion of "*immediate-escalating*" expressions and functions was introduced to propagate the constant evaluation of `consteval` functions upwards.

Then in the cases without `if consteval`, because `ceval(x)` is an immediate invocation that is not a constant expression and not in an immediate function context, it is an *immediate-escalating* expression.

A specialization of a function template marked `constexpr` is also an *immediate-escalating function*.

Then, because this immediate-escalating function contains the immediate-escalating expression (directly in its function body without any other intervening non-block scope), the function itself becomes an *immediate function*, i.e. it will behave as if it is marked `consteval`.

When the outer function itself is an immediate function, then the call `___(42)` itself will be evaluated at compile-time, regardless of the context it is used in and the function body is always manifestly-constant evaluated. So, this works out here and the compile-time path is always chosen. Clang is implementing this correctly.

The only issue I see is with the behavior after P2564 in the cases with `if consteval`. Because the calls to `ceval` are in the `if consteval` body, they are in an *immediate function context* and therefore can't be *immediate-escalating* expressions. Consequently I think the behavior in these cases should be unchanged from before P2564. However, Clang seems to incorrectly choose the compile-time path for `d` and `g`.